# How to disable the download button in ViewerJS?

Tags: jquery, pdf, pdf-generation

Is it possible to disable the download button on a pdf in ViewerJS using JQuery without modifying the provided original code?
I don't want to modify any of the files of the viewerjs, I'd like to do it in another file.

Comment: hiding it with CSS would be ok? or you need to remove the code from the script?

Comment: I need to remove the code from the script if it's possible @GrafiCodeStudio otherwise, hiding it would be ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

HTML

```
<iframe id="iframe" src ="..." width="800" height="500" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JS

```
$('#iframe').ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('#iframe').contents().find('#download').remove();
   }, 100);
});
```

Comment: I have some troubles with the viewer if I `remove` the button. The zoom doesn't work correctly. I don't have these problems when I `hide` the button.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I downloaded ViewerJS, and it included a folder named ViewerJS also. Inside there I found a file index.html. Looking for in the code the control download. Take a look to the pic that I included. I only commented the control and forgot work with css. 
[image]

Comment: This works but the OP didn't want to modify original files.

Answer (score 1):

If found the solution, here you have:

`<script>`

`$(window).load( function() {`

```
   $('#ifr').ready(function(){

        $('#ifr').contents().find('#download').css("display","none");

});
```

`});`

`</script>`

```
`<iframe id="ifr" src ="" width='800' height='1000' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>`
```

Answer (score 0):

taking this page as example(first viewer from top)

```
http://viewerjs.org/examples/
```

<strike>the css solution to hide the button is</strike>:

```
#download { display: none; }
```

<strike>the jQuery solution to remove the button from the generated code is</strike>:

```
$(window).load( function() {
    $('#download').remove();
});
```

EDIT:

I think both solutions are useless because I just noticed the plugin displays documents inside an IFRAME. I'm not sure you can always/easely manipulate iframe contents, even if they point to your very own website.